# Admin group can sudo, but my user in admin group can't

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, sudoers

I'm having trouble giving a user sudo access. I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my new VPS.

I made a user named portaljacker, added it to the admin group, and admin group is in the sudoers file as

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

yet when I use sudo as portaljacker it says:

> sudo: must be setuid root

I have no idea what's wrong since I did this a while ago on a previous VPS (not accessible, long story) and can't remember what I did differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your `sudo` executable has the wrong permissions. Try `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` and see what it says. It should look like `-rwsr-xr-x` (or `---s--x--x`; the `s` needs to be there in that position, though). If the `s` is not there, try running `chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo` as root.

Comment: Worked exactly as you said. It showed -rwxr-xr-x.